# How to call WebClient for localhost:port

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I have have to call api project which is running locally in Visual Studio 2015, and have to call its api from another project running locally.

API Project VS IIS Path
localhost:13591/Home/Index?Id=1

Other Project VS IIS Path
localhost:24591/Home/FetchFromHomeApi

I got the error when trying to access by WebClient, "An exception occurred during a WebClient request".

```
var request = new WebClient();
request.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
request.Headers.Add("AuthHeader", AuthHeaderToken());
request.DownloadString("localhost:13591/Home/Index?Id=1");
```

Comment: And the exception is...

Comment: sorry, it was other due to other error :), error resolved now and its calling :)

Comment: Glad all worked out, Delete this post.

Comment: hahaha how to delete it :D ?